# Facing issue in making rest api(Get) in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest

I have a table named "interviewCategory" and in that there are categories.Now i want to fetch all categories through Rest api. in server.js file i have included my AdminUtils file in which there is function to send responses to getInterviewCategories. Here it is in my server.js file

[image]

here is my adminUtils.js file code

```
var connection = require('./../config');
var helpers = require('../helpers/helper');

module.exports.getInterviewCategories =  function(req,res) {
console.log('in getInterviewCategories function')
helpers.getAllFromDb()
.then(function(categories){
    if(categories == null){
        res.status(400).send({
            meta : {status : 400, message : 'There is some error with query'}
        });
    }
    else{
        res.status(200).send({
            meta : {status : 200 , message : 'Success'},
            data : categories
        });
    }
})
.catch(function(err){
    res.status(500).send({
        meta : {status : 500, message : 'Internal Server Error'}
    });
  })
 }
```

Here is my helpers.js file in which there is a function "getAllFromDb" to fetch all categories from db

```
exports.getAllFromDb = function getAllFromDb() {
console.log('in getAllFromDb Function');
var query = "SELECT * from interviewcategory";
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    connection.query(query,(err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            return reject(err);
        }
        else{
            return resolve(result);
        }
    })
  })
 }
```

Here is my api url

[image]

Here is the error which i am getting when i am hitting the api using POSTMAN.

[image]

Here is my response on console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your express route is wrong. You should create the GET route. So, change the following

`app.post('/api/admin/interview/getCategories', AdminUtills.getInterviewCategories)`

to

`app.get('/api/admin/interview/getCategories', AdminUtills.getInterviewCategories)`